# 301 Redirect Working when Typed, but Not From Google Results

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, redirect

I am having a heck of a time trying to set up a 301 redirect. I have a bigcartel site with a custom domain, redirecting to my new Square Online site. It works when you type the URL in, but it doesn't work when you find the website using google. When you click the site from Google, it goes to the old website.

I went into cPanel and added a 301 Redirect for the entire domain, with or without the "www" to redirect to the new site permanently. I even went into the .htaccess file and checked my settings in there, and it shows:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mywebsite\.square\.site\/" [R=301,L]
```

I know it isn't a time thing, because I set up this redirect months ago. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am adding the following to my home page html page in the header above everything else to see if it helps...

<link rel="canonical" href="pinupally.square.site" />
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=pinupally.square.site" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

Comment: So the two requested URLs are different, actually. Obviously your redirection only applies when the root URL is requested, so without any path. I would assume that the google hits contain a path, since google tries to index the site content.